# Unexpected result from sys.getrefcount

Tags: python, garbage-collection

When I typed:

```
>>> astrd = 123
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(astrd)
3
>>>
```

I am not getting where is `astrd` used 3 times ?

Answer (score 10):

It's not `astrd` that is referenced three times, but the value `123`. `astrd` is simply a name for the (immutable) number 123, which can be referenced however many times. Additionally to that, small integers are usually shared:

```
>>> astrd = 123
>>> sys.getrefcount(astrd)
4
>>> j = 123
>>> sys.getrefcount(astrd)
5
```

In the second assignment, no new integer is created, instead `j` is just a new name for the integer `123`.

However, given very large integers, this does not hold:

```
>>> i = 823423442583
>>> sys.getrefcount(i)
2
>>> j = 823423442583
>>> sys.getrefcount(i)
2
```

Shared integers are an implementation detail of CPython (among others). Since small integers are instantiated very often, sharing them saves a lot of memory. This is made possible by the fact that integers are immutable in the first place.

For the additional reference in the second example, cf. [codeape's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759740/sys-getrefcount/759763#759763).

Answer (score 7):

From the [getrefcount docstring](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount):

> ... The count returned is generally one higher than you might expect, 
>   because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to `getrefcount()`.

The other two references means that python internally is holding two references to the object. Maybe the locals() and globals() dictionaries count as one reference each?

Comment: so when i does a "del astrd" its reference count becomes 0 and is collected by gc ?

Answer (score 6):

I think it counts the references to 123, try other examples, like

```
>>> import sys
>>> astrd = 1
>>> sys.getrefcount(astrd)
177
>>> astrd = 9802374987193847
>>> sys.getrefcount(astrd)
2
>>>
```

The refcount for 9802374987193847 fits codeape's answer.

This is probably because numbers are immutables. If you for example use a list, it will always be 2 (from a clean prompt that is).

Btw, I get 2 for 123 as well, perhaps your setup is somewhat different? Or it might be time related or so?

Answer (score 5):

ints are implemented in a special way, they are cached and shared, that why you don't get 1.

And python, uses reference counted objects. astrd is itself a reference, so you actually get the number of references to the int '123'. Try with another (user-defined) type and you'll get 1.