# Python garbage collection

Tags: python, optimization, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have created some python code which creates an object in a loop, and in every iteration overwrites this object with a new one of the same type. This is done 10.000 times, and Python takes up 7mb of memory every second until my 3gb RAM is used. Does anyone know of a way to remove the objects from memory?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759906/sys-getrefcount-continuation/759970#759970

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information - this depends on the specifics of the object you are creating and what else you're doing with it in the loop. If the object does not create circular references, it should be deallocated on the next iteration. For example, the code

```
for x in range(100000):
  obj = " " * 10000000
```

will not result in ever-increasing memory allocation.

Comment: I am creating circular references in my object. Can't it be deleted manually?

Comment: Python will automatically collect objects with circular references, *unless* any of the objects in a reference cycle have __del__ methods.  If that's the case, garbage objects are moved to the gc.garbage list, and you will have to manually break the reference cycles.  It's better to try to avoid having both __del__ methods and reference cycles.

Comment: One solution to avoiding reference cycles is to use weakrefs: http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html

Answer (score 33):

I think this is circular reference (though the question isn't explicit about this information.)

One way to solve this problem is to manually invoke garbage collection. When you manually run garbage collector, it will sweep circular referenced objects too.

```
import gc

for i in xrange(10000):
    j = myObj()
    processObj(j)
    #assuming count reference is not zero but still
    #object won't remain usable after the iteration

    if !(i%100):
        gc.collect()
```

Here don't run garbage collector too often because it has its own overhead, e.g. if you run garbage collector in every loop, interpretation will become extremely slow.

Answer (score 13):

This is an old error that was corrected for some types in python 2.5. What was happening was that python was not so good at collecting things like empty lists/dictionaries/tupes/floats/ints. In python 2.5 this was fixed...mostly. However floats and ints are singletons for comparisons so once one of those is created it stays around as long as the interpreter is alive. I've been bitten by this worst when dealing with large amount of floats since they have a nasty habit of being unique. This was characterized [for python 2.4](http://evanjones.ca/python-memory.html)  and updated about it being folded into [python 2.5](http://evanjones.ca/python-memory-part2.html)

The best way I've found around it is to upgrade to python 2.5 or newer to take care of the lists/dictionaries/tuples issue. For numbers the only solution is to not let large amounts of numbers get into python. I've done it with my own wrapper to a c++ object, but I have the impression that numpy.array will give similar results.

As a post script I have no idea what has happened to this in python 3, but I'm suspicious that numbers are still part of a singleton. So the memory leak is actually a feature of the language.

Comment: This shouldn't exactly be responsible for the problem as described, though; even Python 2.4 should reuse freed memory (it just didn't return it to the operating system).

Comment: Not sure if my experiment is correct but temporarily creating millions of floats definitely had constant memory usage. Putting the same floats in a `list` increased the memory usage 100MB/s. That was on 2.7... so I guess at least in 2.7 the problem doesn't exit? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

If you're creating circular references, your objects won't be deallocated immediately, but have to wait for a GC cycle to run.

You could use the [weakref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) module to address this problem, or explicitly del your objects after use.

Answer (score 3):

I found that in my case (with Python 2.5.1), with circular references involving classes that have `__del__()` methods, not only was garbage collection not happening in a timely manner, the `__del__()` methods of my objects were never getting called, even when the script exited. So I used [weakref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) to break the circular references and all was well.

Kudos to Miles who provided all the information in his comments for me to put this together.

Comment: If any object in a cycle has a `__del__` method, then the cycle isn't garbage collected by `gc`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15974956/1959808

Answer (score 1):

Here's one thing you can do at the REPL to force a dereferencing of a variable:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> x
5
>>> del x
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: In a typical program, it's easier and clearer to just let your variables go out of scope than explicitly deleting them. Of course, if your whole program is one single long function then nothing will go out of scope until it ends. Which is one reason that a single long function is not a recommended way of writing programs.

Answer (score 0):

weakref can be used for circular object structured code as in the [explained example](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/)