# How to deallocate a typed numpy array? Is setting callback_free_data a viable option?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks, cython

While using an open source Cython library I found a memory leak. The leak seems to come from a typed numpy array, which is not freed from the memory when it goes out of scope. The declaration is the following:

```
cdef np.ndarray[object, ndim=1] my_array = np.empty(my_size, dtype=object)
```

In my understanding, this should be considered by the garbage collector like any other numpy array and the GC should free its memory as soon as the array goes out of scope -- in this case at the end of the function in which it is declared. Apparently this does not happen.

If the array were created using a cython array first, and then casting it to numpy array, one could use the callback_free_data function like described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/p2l2JsxdHJ0) and [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays). However, in this case it is not possible to reach the pointers of `my_array` and it is not possible to set the callback.

Any idea on why this kind of declaration could cause a memory leak and/or how to force the deallocation?

**Update:**

My question was very generic, and I wanted to avoid posting the code because it is a bit intricate, but since someone asked here we go:

```
cdef dijkstra(Graph G, int start_idx, int end_idx):

    # Some code

    cdef np.ndarray[object, ndim=1] fiboheap_nodes = np.empty([G.num_nodes], dtype=object) # holds all of our FiboHeap Nodes Pointers

    Q = FiboHeap()

    fiboheap_nodes[start_idx] = Q.insert(0, start_idx)

    # Some other code where it could perform operations like:
    # Q.decrease_key(fiboheap_nodes[w], vw_distance)

    # End of operations

    # do we need to cleanup the fiboheap_nodes array here?

    return
```

The `FiboHeap` is a Cython wrapper for the c implementation. For example, the insert function looks like this:

```
cimport cfiboheap
from cpython.pycapsule cimport PyCapsule_New, PyCapsule_GetPointer
from python_ref cimport Py_INCREF, Py_DECREF 

cdef inline object convert_fibheap_el_to_pycapsule(cfiboheap.fibheap_el* element):
    return PyCapsule_New(element, NULL, NULL)

cdef class FiboHeap:

    def __cinit__(FiboHeap self):
        self.treeptr = cfiboheap.fh_makekeyheap()
        if self.treeptr is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

    def __dealloc__(FiboHeap self):
        if self.treeptr is not NULL:
            cfiboheap.fh_deleteheap(self.treeptr)

    cpdef object insert(FiboHeap self, double key, object data=None):
        Py_INCREF(data)
        cdef cfiboheap.fibheap_el* retValue = cfiboheap.fh_insertkey(self.treeptr, key, <void*>data)
        if retValue is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

        return convert_fibheap_el_to_pycapsule(retValue)
```

The `__dealloc__()` function works as it is supposed to, so the FiboHeap is released from the memory at the end of the function `dijkstra(...)`. My guess is that something is going wrong with the pointers contained in fiboheap_nodes.
Any guess?

Comment: It really should be freed. By far the most likely explanation is that a reference to it has been kept elsewhere. Given it's an `object` array, it's not completely impossible that it contains a circular reference to itself (in which case a call to `gc.collect()` might work).

Comment: Other than that you'd probably have to post the code (or a pointer to the open source library in question) to get a useful answer (preferably in a minimal complete form). Or at very least a more detailed description - is this a global variable, a local function variable, a member of a class... etc?

Comment: I tried `gc.collect()` already and it does not work. It appears in this weird cases (arrays containing object pointers), the gc does not behave deterministically (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974561/i-cant-get-dealloc-be-called-when-deleting-an-object)).

Comment: My first thought is that this might be related to `tp_traverse` (the function used by the garbage collector to find cycles) - Cython apparently generates it automatically, but it won't know about the pointers contained in the C `fiboheap`. I found this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/OW3z9HsxlNI but actually doing it looks difficult... (I may have a go sometime later, possibly)

Comment: Another thought - in the code you've shown the objects aren't getting their reference decreased when `FiboHeap` is deallocated. If that code is complete you certainly have a memory leak for the objects stored on the heap.

Comment: It seems you spot the problem @DavidW! I posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285729/confusing-reference-ownership-how-to-properly-deallocate-via-py-decref-object) more focused on the usage of `Py_DECREF`. If you wanna write a quick answer for this one I'll be happy to accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (solved in the comments) turned out not to be the deallocation of the numpy array. Instead, the numpy array held a bunch of `Fiboheap` objects, which themselves held pointers to a bunch of Python objects. It's these objects that weren't freed.

When the Python object pointers in the `Fiboheap` were acquired (in `insert`) their reference count was incremented to ensure they were kept alive. However, when the `Fiboheap` was destroyed (in `__dealloc__`) the reference count of the Python objects it held was not decreased, causing the memory leak. The solution is to ensure that `Py_DECREF` is called on all the held Python objects during `__dealloc__`.

---

There's potentially a second, more challenging problem waiting to appear: it might be possible for the objects held by the `Fiboheap` to themselves contain a reference back to the `Fiboheap`, maybe indirectly. Python uses the function [`tp_tranverse`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_traverse) to find these loops and `tp_clear` to break them. Cython will automatically generate a `tp_traverse` for its `cdef` classes, however since it has no way of knowing about the Python object pointers hidden within the C `Fiboheap` structure it won't handle these correctly (maybe generating another memory leak).

This is a probably unlikely to happen in reality, so may not be worth worrying about, but it's something to be aware of. A [newsgroup post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/OW3z9HsxlNI) describes a means of generating custom `tp_traverse` functions in Cython. For most applications this should not be necessary - it's only the mixture of Cython `object` and `PyObject*` that makes it slightly possible here.