# Confusing reference ownership: how to properly deallocate (via Py_DECREF) objects of an object?

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, cython

I was analysing the following code, which compiles and runs correctly, but generates a memory leak.

The `cfiboheap` is a C implementation of a Fibonacci Heap and the following code is a Cython wrapper (a part of it) for `cfiboheap`.

My doubts starts on the insert function. The object `data` has been created somewhere and passed to the function `insert()`. Since the function wants to add this object to the fiboheap it increases its reference count. But afterwards? To whom the ownership goes? In my understanding, the C function `fh_insertkey()` just borrows the ownership. Then it returns a proprietary pointer that needs to be incapsulated, and then returned by `insert()`. Cool. But my object `data` and its ref count? By creating the capsule I'm creating a new object, but I'm not decreasing the ref count of `data`. This produces the memory leak.

(Note that commenting out `Py_INCREF` or adding `Py_DECREF` before the return of `insert()` results in a segmentation fault.)

My questions are:

1) Why is it necessary to increment the ref count of `data` during the `insert()`?

2) Why is it not necessary to use a `Py_DECREF` during the `extract()`?

3) More generally, how can I exactly keep track of the reference ownership when jumping between C and Python?

4) How to properly deallocate an object like this FiboHeap? Should I use preventively a `Py_XDECREF` in `__dealloc__()` and, if yes, how?

Thanks!

```
cimport cfiboheap
from cpython.pycapsule cimport PyCapsule_New, PyCapsule_GetPointer
from python_ref cimport Py_INCREF, Py_DECREF 

cdef inline object convert_fibheap_el_to_pycapsule(cfiboheap.fibheap_el* element):
    return PyCapsule_New(element, NULL, NULL)

cdef class FiboHeap:

    def __cinit__(FiboHeap self):
        self.treeptr = cfiboheap.fh_makekeyheap()
        if self.treeptr is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

    def __dealloc__(FiboHeap self):
        if self.treeptr is not NULL:
            cfiboheap.fh_deleteheap(self.treeptr)

    cpdef object insert(FiboHeap self, double key, object data=None):
        Py_INCREF(data)
        cdef cfiboheap.fibheap_el* retValue = cfiboheap.fh_insertkey(self.treeptr, key, <void*>data)
        if retValue is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

        return convert_fibheap_el_to_pycapsule(retValue)

    cpdef object extract(FiboHeap self):
        cdef void* ret = cfiboheap.fh_extractmin(self.treeptr)
        if ret is NULL:
            raise IndexError("FiboHeap is empty")

        return <object> ret

    cpdef object decrease_key(FiboHeap self,  object element, double newKey):
        cdef void* ret = cfiboheap.fh_replacekey(self.treeptr, convert_pycapsule_to_fibheap_el(element), newKey)
        if ret is NULL:
            raise IndexError("New Key is Bigger")

        return <object> ret
```

Note that this hasn't been written by me, but I'm using this example to better understand obj referencing and to stop the leak (since I am actually using the code).

The main code that makes use of `FiboHeap` (and where the leak happens) looks like this:

```
cdef dijkstra(Graph G, int start_idx, int end_idx):

    cdef np.ndarray[object, ndim=1] fiboheap_nodes = np.empty([G.num_nodes], dtype=object) # holds all of our FiboHeap Nodes Pointers
    Q = FiboHeap()
    fiboheap_nodes[start_idx] = Q.insert(0, start_idx)
    # Then occasionally:
    Q.insert(...)
    Q.decrease_key(...)
    Q.extract()

    return
```

`extract` is not a peek, but a proper pop, so it is deleting the C element in the C fiboheap.

In conclusion: it seems clear that the ref count of `data` causes a memory leak, but why? And how to stop it?

Comment: The initial (but different) question about this memory leak can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251216/how-to-deallocate-a-typed-numpy-array-is-setting-callback-free-data-a-viable-op).

Comment: Why are you making a capsule at all? It seems useless and unsafe. Also, does `extract` do a peek or a pop?

Comment: I'm posting here since you mentioned it in your initial question - I don't think I understand what `fiboheap` does well enough to really answer this one. It'd avoid trying to use `PyObject*`s and reference counting in Cython - it's very hard to get right. The question @user2357112 asked about what `extract` does is key here....

Comment: The `extract` is a pop! So it destroys the element of the Heap. @user2357112 the code is not written by me, but I realized it was causing a memory leak while I was using it. I am both trying to stop the memory leak and understanding the object referencing better, since this is a kinda weird usage. I edited the question a bit.

Comment: @user2357112 Why there shouldn't be a capsule? The C function `cfiboheap.fh_insertkey` is returning a C pointer, which has to be passed to other Python functions afterwards, like `decrease_key(...)`.

Comment: @Gioker: It makes sense with `decrease_key`, but when I made that comment, `decrease_key` wasn't there. The capsule wasn't usable for anything in that version.

Comment: @user2357112 Yep, sorry, my bad! I didn't include `decrease_key` initially because I though it was out of scope in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It is necessary to increase the reference count in `insert` because its reference count will be automatically decreased at the end of insert. Cython does not know you are storing the object for later. (You can inspect the generated C code to see the `DECREF` at the end of the function). If `insert` is called with an object of reference count 1 (i.e. `.insert(SomeObject())`, then the object would be destroyed at the end of insert without the `INCREF`

2) If the object is removed from the `cfiboheap` during `extract` then you should do a `DECREF` to acknowledge the fact that you no longer hold it. Cast it to object first (so you still hold a reference to it)

```
   cdef void* ret = cfiboheap.fh_extractmin(self.treeptr) # refcount is 1 here (from the INCREF when it was stored)
   if ret==NULL:
        # ...

   ret_obj = <object>ret
   # reference count should be 2 here - one for being on the heap and one for ret_obj. Casting to object increases the refcount in Cython
   Py_DECREF(ret_obj) # 1 here
   return ret_obj
```

3) Honestly you try not to use `PyObject*` if you can avoid it! It's much better to let Cython do the work. If you can't avoid it then you just need to ensure `INCREF` is called once when you store the object, and `DECREF` is called once when you stop storing it.

4) You do need to decref the remaining objects on the heap in `__dealloc__`. A very easy way to do that might be to all `extract` until the `cfiboheap` is empty:

```
try:
    while True:
        self.extract()
except IndexError:
    pass # ignore the error - we're done emptying the heap
```

---

A comment about the use of capsules: who owns the `fibheap_el` that they point to (and when does this get destructed)? If it gets destructed when the `cfiboheap` gets destructed then you have the issue of a capsule with an invalid pointer still being alive. Using this capsule somewhere might end up causing problems. If it doesn't get destructed by the `cfiboheap` then you potentially have another memory leak.

Comment: Answer to point 1) is still a bit unclear. The C function `insert` should only borrow the reference of the element, so why Cython should decrease the ref count? Instead, I think the problem is related to what explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#thin-ice), that is the pointer to a valid element of the heap might get disposed during a subsequent extract, possible invalidating a subsequent insert in the same position. In this sense you are right when you say that Cython does not know that I'm storing the element for later.