# How do I prevent memory leak when I load large pickle files in a for loop?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-3.x, garbage-collection, pickle

I have 50 pickle files that are 0.5 GB each.
Each pickle file is comprised of a list of custom class objects.
I have no trouble loading the files individually using
the following function:

```
def loadPickle(fp):
    with open(fp, 'rb') as fh:
        listOfObj = pickle.load(fh)
    return listOfObj
```

However, when I try to iteratively load the files
I get a memory leak.

```
l = ['filepath1', 'filepath2', 'filepath3', 'filepath4']
for fp in l:
    x = loadPickle(fp)
    print( 'loaded {0}'.format(fp) )
```

My memory overflows before `loaded filepath2` is printed.
How can I write code that guarantees that only a single pickle is loaded during each iteration?

Answers to related questions on SO suggest using objects defined in the `weakref` module or explicit garbage collection using the `gc` module, but I am having a difficult time understanding how I would apply these methods to my particular use case. This is because I have an insufficient understanding of how referencing works under the hood.

Related: [Python garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035489/python-garbage-collection)

Comment: try adding `x = None` right after `for fp in l:`

Comment: Hi Ionut Hulub, thank you. It worked!

Comment: There's no actual memory leak here. It's just that the old `x` value can't be released until after the new value is assigned, so you need enough memory to have two values in memory at once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can fix that by adding `x = None` right after `for fp in l:`.

The reason this works is because it will dereferenciate variable `x`, hance allowing the python garbage collector to free some virtual memory before calling `loadPickle()` the second time.

Comment: This isn't actually guaranteed to work. Python is _allowed_ to dispose of the object once you stop referencing it, but it isn't _required_ to. Fortunately, the CPython implementation _will_ do so, as long as you don't have any circular references anywhere, but code that depends on something that's explicitly documented to not be guaranteed should at the very least come with comments and warnings…

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do `del x`? Just to be sure that variable `x` will be dereferenciated.

Comment: I don't think that makes a difference, but that's a valid alternative.

Comment: I have situation when it does not work - memory used still accumulates.

Comment: @Zbyszek: with the `del` or the `=None` alternative? :)

Comment: @Roelant del shouldn't be needed but tried both back then - I tried to pickle big amount of small images data from opencv - finally I just saved those in png format and packed into zip instead of trying to pickle them in batches

Comment: This is so weird. The `del` instruction didn't work but adding a `= None` statement did it on my side.