# How to prevent memory leaks in RubyMotion when reading large files in loops

Tags: ruby, cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks, rubymotion

RubyMotion is supposed to do automatic memory management:

> RubyMotion provides automatic memory management; you do not need to
>   reclaim unused objects.

but, when reading large files in a loop, I encounter huge memory leaks: hundreds of MB/s per seconds, exactly as if my reading buffer was never released.

The leaks mostly go away if I use  `release`  on the reading buffer on every loop. The problem is,  `release` makes the application crash when the loop is finished.

```
  def readBigBinaryFile(file)
#   PURE RUBY WOULD BE
#   source=File.open(file,'r')
    source =NSFileHandle.fileHandleForReadingAtPath(file)
    buffer_size=4096
    offset=0
    size=File.size(file)
    while ( offset + buffer_size ) <= size
#      PURE RUBY WOULD BE
#      source.seek(offset) 
#      abuffer = source.read( buffer_size )
#      abuffer=abuffer.to_s

      source.seekToFileOffset(offset)
      abuffer = source.readDataOfLength(buffer_size)
      offset+=buffer_size
      @dataPointer ||= Pointer.new(:uchar,4) 
      abuffer.getBytes(@dataPointer, length: 4)
      # memory leaks very rapidly in GBs if we don't release the buffer…
      # but this relase action will make the application crash once the doSomething lookp is finished
      abuffer.release
    end
    source.closeFile
    return false
  end
```

The loop is:

```
x=0
while x < 10000
  my_scan_binary_instance=Scan_binary.new()        result=my_scan_binary_instance.readBigBinaryFile(NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource("sample1MBfile", ofType:"img"))
  puts result.to_s
  x+=1
end
puts "if we have used 'abuffer.release', we are going to crash now"
```

I tested a pure-Ruby implementation, and had no memory leak at all, and no need for the release call.

I found "[How do I prevent memory leak when I load large pickle files in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288936/how-do-i-prevent-memory-leak-when-i-load-large-pickle-files-in-a-for-loop)" about a memory leak in a Python loop, but the accepted solution doing `abuffer=nil` at the beginning of the `while block` in `readBigBinaryFile` did not work.

Is this a bug in RubyMotion's automatic memory management, or is this expected?
And most importantly, how can I read big files in loops without increasing the memory usage of my RubyMotion app?

I have created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/michaelcinquin/d8272675ea3c582f3c4362d0555de0e0) with the working pure Ruby implementation, and [a repo](https://github.com/michaelcinquin/rubymotionCrashOnReadFileLoop) of a sample application reproducing the crash.

Comment: I'd recommend reading "[ask]", and especially the link to http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. "[mcve]" specifies that your sample app has to be in the question _itself_. Links to other sites are prone to rot then break, making the question worthless to others in the future.

Comment: the external links are a commodity, the question itself hopefully embeds the code that makes the question complete, and useful for others, now and later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your loop body in `autorelease_pool do ... end`.  This should cause
the autoreleased objects to be freed each loop.  Assigning `nil` to `abuffer` at the end of the loop will allow the buffer memory to be freed as there will be no more references to it.

```
while ( offset + buffer_size ) <= size
  autorelease_pool do
    source.seekToFileOffset(offset)
    abuffer = source.readDataOfLength(buffer_size)
    offset+=buffer_size
    @dataPointer ||= Pointer.new(:uchar,4) 
    abuffer.getBytes(@dataPointer, length: 4)

    abuffer = nil
  end
end
```

Comment: works great! Even less memory leaking if I also put an autorelease around `my_scan_binary_instance=Scan_binary.new()`. [Link to Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will fix it for sure, but maybe try replacing

```
abuffer = source.readDataOfLength(buffer_size)
```

with

```
abuffer = WeakRef.new(source.readDataOfLength(buffer_size))
```

See "[4.1. Weak References](http://www.rubymotion.com/developers/guides/manuals/cocoa/runtime/#_weak_references)" for info on `WeakRef`.

Making this change would mean you would also remove the call to `abuffer.release`.

Comment: good idea! But it dos not work. So I tried putting WeakRefs everywhere I could, and a `.weak!` at the the while loop in `doSomething`… to no avail! I also read https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/12/09/cyclical-references-rubymotion/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use better anchor text for links and refrain from using "Edit" or "Update". Questions and answers have revision history so we can see changes if necessary; Add changes as if you'd written them initially. Better anchor text helps keep the content readable. It's also a really good idea to summarize the information at that link in your answer so if the link dies the useful information is still available for future searchers.

Comment: @MichaelC My best suggestion then would be to ask on the [RubyMotion forums](http://community.rubymotion.com/) where you'll probably get better visibility for your question.