# python garbage collection and _ underscore in interpreter environment

Tags: python, garbage-collection

If a class is defined in interpreter environment:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.x = val
```

Then instantiated without names:

```
>>> C(1)
>>> C(2)
>>>
```

Then we can use underscore _ to refer to `C(2)`, so here is my question:

- Since the underscore '_' refer to `C(2)`, can we say the reference
  counter for `C(2)` is **still 1**? So the python gc will **not free** the
  memory taken by `C(2)`?
- As far as I know, after these `C(2)` is executed, no names will refer to `C(1)`, so can I say **as soon as** `C(2)` is executed, `C(1)`'s
  memory will be **freed** by python gc?

These are actually 4 questions, one bold font to one.

gc: short for garbage collection

**EDIT**

Let me make my first question more clear by commenting directly into the codes.

```
>>> C(1) # Press Enter Key and run
>>> 
>>> At Here, what is the exact reference count for the previous anonymous object "C(1)"? 
>>> And how to prove?
>>> 
>>> C(2) # Press Enter Key and run
>>> 
>>> At Here, what is the exact reference count for the previous anonymous object "C(1)"?
>>> And how to prove?
```

Comment: Yes, essentially. You can explore this empirically using `sys.getrefcount`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I run sys.getrefcount(C(2)) again, I will expect the result will be 2 because the last _ underscore is referencing it. But the result is 1. So I think your explanation is not convincing enough.

Comment: `sys.getrefcount(C(2)) ` creates an entirely new  `C` object, passes it to refcount, and *never binds it to a name*. There is never more than one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How can I make sure C(2) still exists in memory except using underscore? I mean, is there a way to check the **last** C(2) still holds a refcount?

Comment: There are *two* `C` objects with `val == 2`. Unless you bind them to a name, then **no**, there will only ever be `1` when you get it's refcount. All the REPL does is bind the result of evaluating the last expression to `_`. You can instead do `x = C(2)` then `x` then `sys.refcount(x)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think I didn't explain my question clear. I modified my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C(1)` or `C(2)` as last line of the interpreter behaves differently when they are in the middle or to the up of the code.

If `C(1)` is at the last line, python interpreter will store it as `<__main__.C object at 0x00000000********>`, so actually it will have a name attached to it. If you check `number_of_instances(C)`, the result will be 1.

If `C(1)` is not at the last line, this temporary anonymous object is just destroyed and disappeared.

Check the following testing codes.

You can use `number_of_instances` to show if there is any `C` object resides in memory.

```
import gc

def name_of_instances(cls):
    return [obj for obj in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(obj, cls)]

def number_of_instances(cls):
    return len([obj for obj in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(obj, cls)])
```

1.anonymous object not at last line

```
In [12]: C(1)
    ...: C(2)
    ...: print(number_of_instances(C))
    ...:
0

In [13]:
```

2.anonymous object at last line

```
In [6]: C(1)
Out[6]: <__main__.C at 0x6a97ba8>

In [7]: print(number_of_instances(C))
   ...: print(name_of_instances(C))
   ...:
1
[<__main__.C object at 0x0000000006A97BA8>]

In [8]: C(2)
Out[8]: <__main__.C at 0x6a9b518>

In [9]: print(number_of_instances(C))
   ...: print(name_of_instances(C))
   ...:
2
[<__main__.C object at 0x0000000006A97BA8>, <__main__.C object at 0x0000000006A9B518>]
```

3.underscore `_` will remember `C(3)` if it is the last line

```
In [13]: C(3)
Out[13]: <__main__.C at 0x6aa06d8>

In [14]: type(_)
Out[14]: __main__.C
```

But in this case, the reference counter never counts reference from `_`, it only counts `<__main__.C object at 0x0000000006AA06D8>` which you didn't observe.

A guess here: `_` is not in `gc.garbage` list. If you run `C(1)`, `print(number_of_instances(C))` successively, `number_of_instances` will not check into `_` which may be storing the previous `C(1)`

See: [sys.getrefcount continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759906/sys-getrefcount-continuation/)

Answer (score 2):

@allen, thank you so much for your answer.

Based on your guess, I made the following code:

```
In [3]: {'a': 1}
Out[3]: {'a': 1}

In [4]: C(1)
   ...: print(_)
   ...: print(type(_))
   ...: print(number_of_instances(C))
   ...:
{'a': 1}
<class 'dict'>
0

In [5]:
```

So the _ underscore is only used for storing the value of last expression in interpreter of **"Single Step Mode"**, not for **"Continuous Mode"**.

This might be a common mistake made by beginners.

Anyway, thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Thank you! I have a related question, maybe you'll know the answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/63222197/854477