# If I rassign a variable, will the object it referred to before be deleted?

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection

If I were to run

```
class Myclass():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

var1 = Myclass(1) # initializes the first instance of Myclass
var1 = Myclass(2) # initializes the second instance of Myclass
```

would the first instance of Myclass linger around in memory? Would the garbage collector (?) free up the space? Do I have to call `del var1` to properly free the memory at runtime?

The background of my question is that I run a large loop where in every iteration I need a different instance of a specific class. While I call `del` explicitly at the moment, it would be nice to know the default behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Overwriting `var1` with a new object will decrease the reference counter of the original object referenced by `var1`. **If the reference count of an object is zero**, the object is destroyed (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/759970/3214872)).

The actual answer is a lot more complex than this, and I don't think I feel comfortable delving too much in depth with the explanation (hopefully someone will step in or point you to another question, I'm fairly certain this is a duplicate).

The problem is, Python's garbage collector is implementation-dependent and even in one implementation it can adopt different policies.

Answer (score 1):

When you declaration a new instance your will got different memory space, you can simple check it by `id()` build-in function.

```
In [2]: id( Myclass(1))
Out[2]: 4481511576

In [3]: id( Myclass(1))
Out[3]: 4481591488
```

So, back to your question, if you run multi-times inside your loop. you have to alloc/dealloc memory each time! That's sadly, so if you really want keep the speed up. you can make your object as simple as you can by define `__slots__` to keep your object simple even can be fly! check this [how to play with slots](http://www.elfsternberg.com/2009/07/06/python-what-the-hell-is-a-slot/)

Comment: But isn't it the garbage collector's job to recognize when I overwrite the access to an object (besides direct pointer handling) and free up that memory on the go? Of course there will be a new object created, but does the first object persist in memory?

Comment: @Neuneck The first instance will have ref-counter for GC used! you don't need to care about the memory-leak question!

Comment: @GPhilo Maybe no complete answer! he/she want to improve the speed of multi generate new object!