# Understanding reference count of class variable

Tags: python

This is an attempt to better understand how reference count works in Python.

Let's create a class and instantiate it. The instance's reference count would be `1` (`getrefcount` displays `2` because it's own internal structures reference that class instance increasing reference count by `1`):

```
>>> from sys import getrefcount as grc
>>> class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 100000


>>> a = A()
>>> grc(a)
2
```

`a`'s internal variable `x` has `2` references:

```
>>> grc(a.x)
3
```

I expected it to be referenced by `a` and by `A`'s `__init__` method. Then I decided to check.

So I created a temporary variable `b` in the `__main__` namespace just to be able to access the variable `x`. It increased the ref-number by `1` for it to become `3` (as expected):

```
>>> b = a.x
>>> grc(a.x)
4
```

Then I deleted the class instance and the ref count decreased by `1`:

```
>>> del a
>>> grc(b)
3
```

So now there are `2` references: one is by `b` and one is by `A` (as I expected).

By deleting `A` from `__main__` namespace I expect the count to decrease by `1` again.

```
>>> del A
>>> grc(b)
3
```

But it doesn't happen. There is no class `A` or its instances that may reference `100000`, but still it's referenced by something other than `b` in `__main__` namespace.

So, my question is, what is `100000` referenced by apart from `b`?

---

**BrenBarn** suggested that I should use `object()` instead of a number which may be stored somewhere internally.

```
>>> class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = object()


>>> a = A()
>>> b = a.x
>>> grc(a.x)
3
>>> del a
>>> grc(b)
2
```

After deleting the instance `a` there were only one reference by `b` which is very logical.

The only thing that is left to be understood is why it's not that way with number `100000`.

Comment: My guess, does `A.__dict__` ?

Comment: @JakobBowyer But when I delete `A`, then `A.__dict__` should be garbage collected because it's not referenced by anything (as I understand).

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759740/unexpected-result-from-sys-getrefcount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.x` is the integer 10000.  This constant is referenced by the code object corresponding to the `__init__()` method of `A`.  Code objects always include references to all literal constants in the code:

```
>>> def f(): return 10000
>>> f.__code__.co_consts
(None, 10000)
```

The line

```
del A
```

only deletes the name `A` and decreases the reference count of `A`.  In Python 3.x (but not in 2.x), classes often include some cyclic references, and hence are only garbage collected when you explicitly run the garbage collector.  And indeed, using

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

after `del A` does lead to the reduction of the reference count of `b`.

Comment: Shouldn't deleting `A` lead to deleting `__init__` as it's only referenced by `A` (as I understand)?

Comment: Oh. I see now. Reference count of `A` is `4` before deleting from `__main__`. So this deleting will only reduce it by `1`. What is the other objects which reference `A`?

Comment: @ovgolovin: I just noticed I cannot reproduce your results.  For me, the clas `A` actually *does* get deleted, and the reference count of `b` *does* decrease.  The only other thing I can think of:  Be careful with the `_` of the interactive interpreter.  When in doubt, better do experiments with reference counts in a script rather than in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: I use Python 3.2, if it matters.

Comment: I checked. Python 3.2 prints `5` as the result of [this code](http://ideone.com/SuEri). And Python 2.6 prints `2`.

Comment: And, if I understand it right, in the case of Python 3.2, constant `10000` is referenced by `__init__` code object of `A` which is not garbage collected as it has 3 references apart from `A` in `__main__`.

Comment: Could you please write a few words about code object that references constants in function definitions (which explains the difference between using `100000` and `object()`). I think it may be useful for those who will be reading this thread.

Comment: @ovgolovin: Code objects also reference constants in Python 2.x.  The difference is that there appear back-references to the class object somewhere in Python 3.x (probably in the MRO) that do not exist in 2.x, and those back-references prevent immediate garbage collection.

Comment: And what comments should I leave?

Comment: I usually read all the comments if the topic is interesting, even those which were later disproved (because it lets me to understand the logic and the source of mistakes and learn something even from it).

Comment: @ovgolovin: Well, fine. :)  I try to clean up really useless stuff, also to improve search engine results.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that this is an artifact of your using an integer as your test value.  Python sometimes stores integer objects for later re-use, because they are immutable.  When I run your code using `self.x = object()` instead (which will always create a brand-new object for x) I do get `grc(b)==2` at the end.

Comment: You are right! Changing `100000` to `object()` altered the numbers returned to `getrefcount`. I'll update the question.

Comment: @ovgolovin: Of course it does, because the code object can only reference *constants* appearing in the code.  This is completely unrelated to any integer object reuse, though.  Integers are not randomly cached for later reuse.  Python only holds a cache of small integers (usually from -5 to 256), which are created at interpreter start and used whenever necessary.  All other integers are created on demand and never reused.

Comment: Downvoting:  While the observation is accurate, the reason given in this answer is wrong.

Comment: The difference is that `object()` is only called when **instance** of `A` is initialized. But `100000` is referenced by `A`'s `__init__` code object. So the reference counts are different. See **Sven Marnach**'s answer for elaborate explanation.