# I am getting confused in counting the reference variables. How to count the number of reference variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

This code is written in Object Oriented Programming in Python.How to count reference variables in this program.I tried printing the ID's of these Objects but it didn't helped me.

```
class Computer:
        def __init__(self):
            self.no_of_legs=4
            self.glass_top=None
            self.wooden_top=None
Obj1=Computer()
Obj2=Computer()
Obj3=Obj2
Obj2=Obj1
```

Comment: Assuming that those four final lines aren't supposed to be indented (which would be a syntax error), you have three variables, referring to two distinct objects.  `Obj1` and `Obj2` refer to one of them, `Obj3` is the only remaining reference to the other one originally held in `Obj2`.

Comment: Why do you need counting references?

Comment: @JanStránský I want to count reference variables to know the concept of reference variables and also it is a question in one of the quiz.

Comment: @jasonharper syntax error came due to copy,paste of code from compiler directly and i have changed it. Can you explain me the same by counting the reference variables. I am getting confused while counting the reference variables

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874499/understanding-reference-count-of-class-variable) using [sys.getrefcount](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sys.getrefcount](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount):

```py
from sys import getrefcount
class Computer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.no_of_legs=4
        self.glass_top=None
        self.wooden_top=None
Obj1=Computer()
Obj2=Computer()
print(getrefcount(Obj1)) # 2
print(getrefcount(Obj2)) # 2
Obj3=Obj2
Obj2=Obj1
print(getrefcount(Obj1)) # 3
print(getrefcount(Obj2)) # 3
print(getrefcount(Obj3)) # 2
```